# retrieved data from db to textarea and radio type

Tags: javascript

how to retrieved data from db to radio type

```
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="jenis" id="radio3" 
        onclick="enableTxtBox1()" type="radio" value="Cuti Tahunan" />
    <label class="form-check-label">CUTI TAHUNAN</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="jenis" id="radio4"             
        onclick="enableTxtBox1()" type="radio" value="Cuti Sakit"/>
    <label class="form-check-label">CUTI SAKIT</label>    
</div>

<script>
    $('#ModalCenter').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var jenis = $(e.relatedTarget).data('jenis');
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="jenis"]').val(jenis);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your DB should ideally be wrapped in an REST endpoint that returns JSON.
Then, use AJAX to call that endpoint and parse the JSON response,

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should find the element by id instead of name, i.e.:

```js
$(e.currentTarget).find('input[id="radio3"]').val(jenis);
$(e.currentTarget).find('input[id="radio4"]').val(jenis);
```

Comment: still not working. I want my radio button checked in a form.

Answer (score 0):

Setting value using `$(..).val()` to `textarea` is fine, bu not for Checkbox or Radio. You need to use `attr` method of the input selector

Do this to update check / uncheck it

```
   $(...).attr('checked', true);

   /// to uncheck,
   $(...).attr('checked', false);
```

To make it more dynamic, you can check input type using the below code

```
    var isCheckboxOrRadio = $(...).is(':radio, :checkbox'); 

    console.log(isCheckboxOrRadio);    // result will be true or false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `checked`attribute if the value retrieved from the database is the value of the radio.

```
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="jenis" id="radio3" 
        onclick="enableTxtBox1()" type="radio" value="Cuti Tahunan" 
        <?php echo $data_retrieved['jenis'] == 'Cuti Tahunan' ? 'checked': '' ; />
    <label class="form-check-label">CUTI TAHUNAN</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="jenis" id="radio4"             
        onclick="enableTxtBox1()" type="radio" value="Cuti Sakit"
        <?php echo $data_retrieved['jenis'] == 'Cuti Sakit' ? 'checked': '' ; />
    <label class="form-check-label">CUTI SAKIT</label>    
</div>
```